# Django form __init__ doesn't work in userprofileform

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, user-profile

I'm stuck with the initialization of my userprofileform in the post method of a CBV and the instance receive a None object from the call to super()...
the model is quite standard : a user and his profile; the uerprofile model has an user attribute (*onetoone*)

**models.py**

```
[...]

class User(AbstractUser):
 """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), unique=False, max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), unique=False, max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True) upload_to=PathAndRename("avatars/"))
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    organization = models.CharField(_('organization'), null=True,unique=False, max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(_('city'), unique=False, max_length=100, null=True)
    country = CountryField(blank_label=_('select country'), null=True)

    subscribe_newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                choices=settings.LANGUAGES,
                                default=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

    User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        #import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        self.city=(self.city or '').lower()
        self.organization=(self.organization or '').lower()
        self.website=(self.website or '').lower()
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        self.user.save() 
[...]
```

**forms.py**

```
[...]
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'website','city','country','organization','subscribe_newsletter')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            self.instance.user=user
        except:
            pass
        try:
            self.fields['first_name'].initial = self.instance.user.first_name
            self.fields['last_name'].initial = self.instance.user.last_name
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
[...]
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.context={}
        super().__init__()

    def get(self,request):

        profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile, prefix='profile')
        self.context['profile_form']=profile_form
        return render(request,'account/profile.html', self.context)


    def post(self,request):
        #import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        if request.POST.get('action',)=='profile':

            profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, user=request.user, prefix='profile')
            if profile_form.is_valid():
                profile_form.save()
                info={'title':_('PROFILE SAVED !'),'desc':_('your profile has been successfully updated')}
                self.context['infos']=[info]
                return render(request,'info.html', self.context)
            else:
                self.context['errors']=get_form_errors_list(profile_form.errors)

        elif request.POST.get('action',)=='avatar':
            pass

        self.context['profile_form']=profile_form
        return render(request,'account/profile.html', self.context)
[...]
```

The error occurs in the post method of the view when I affect UserProfileForm to profile_form. The debug toolbar return *"UserProfile has no user"*.
The **init** method of UserProfileForm works with the get method of the view (the instance is set whith the user.profile) but the instance is not given while posting (throwing user.profile would be nonsense as the data are contained in the resquest.POST)...

Comment: During Form initialisation when __init__ is called the user variable is set to none because you are not passing the logged in user to kwargs. If user is logged in set user=self.request.user

Comment: I do not understand. you mean _user=self.request.user_ is not passed even if it's an argument in the instantiation of UserProfileForm when I'm writing,   
_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST,_ ***user=request.user*** _, prefix='profile')_ ?,
however in I catch it in the __init__ kwargs :, 
`ipdb> kwargs
{'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: david@flowka.com>>, 'prefix': 'profile'}
ipdb>`

Comment: on the other hand, self.instance has a none object after the call to _super(UserProfileForm)_ :

`ipdb> self
<UserProfileForm bound=True, valid=Unknown, fields=(first_name;last_name;phone;website;city;country;organization;subscribe_newsletter)>`
`ipdb> self.instance
<UserProfile: UserProfile object (None)>`

Comment: at least, it work if i'm passing those kwargs too__init__ :
_profile_form = UserProfileForm(_ ***data=request.POST*** _,_ ***instance=request.user.profile*** _, prefix='profile')_ but I really don't understand why ?